# Paste text with an embedded hyperlink using AutoHotKeys

Tags: url, hyperlink, autohotkey, clipboard

I just began AutoHotKeys today, and am still unfamiliar with how most of it works, but I have been able to successfully create a host of auto-replace hotkeys.  I am now trying for my first more complicated problem: how to auto-replace with not only text or a URL, but text hyperlinked with a URL.

I found this StackOverflow for the function [SetClipboardHTML](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=80706), as well as [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/x94qmm/linking_to_a_site_hyperlinking_in_ahk/) referencing it, but between them have still been unable to resolve the issue.  It's possible I'm not using a recent enough version of AHK (I downloaded 1.1, but I don't know how to see more specific detail than that, and SetClipboardHTML says it requires 1.1.33.

But if it's not an update issue, I'd greatly appreciate a simple example with no extra complicating details (this is the first time I'm even using Send and Return, all my other hotkeys are merely in the ::call::replace format).  I've tried a variety of options, but I can't make it work.  For Google.com, here's the best I've come up with:

```
#SingleInstance Force
Hotstring(":*X:.gl", "GoogleLink")
Return

GoogleLink:
    SetClipboardHTML(<"a href='https://google.com'>Google.com</a>",, "Google.com")
    Send, ^v
Return
```

I also am not sure yet how to debug AHK (I'm running it in VSCode), so the only way I'm discovering it isn't working is by trying to reload the script and it then telling me there's an error.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have this code that may do what you need.

```
#Persistent
    OnClipboardChange("Clipboard_to_html")  ;   call the function "clipboard_to_html" anytime your clipboard changes
Return


Clipboard_to_html() {

    FileDelete,% "a.c"  ;   if the temp file used to get all chars exist, it'll be deleted, avoiding getting previous data with the current one
    Sleep, 100

    FileAppend,% ClipboardAll, a.c  ;   input the new data to a temp file

    Loop
        if  FileExist("a.c")    ;   wait the all the clipboard data be inputed in the file
            Break

    html := bin2str("a.c")  ;   store in "html" var the data
    RegExMatch(html, "<html>(.*?)<\/html>", match)  ;   remove unnecessary stuff from the data
    html := match
    if  InStr(html, "Retrieving data")  ;   some times it'll not be able to retrieve all the data(dunno why), so it end the function without updating the clipboard.
        Return

    FileDelete,% "a.c"  ;   delete the temp file

    Clipboard := html   ;   set the html content to your clipboard

}

bin2str(file_path)  {   ; convert the raw binary data from the clipboardAll to chars, byte by byte(yeah, could be a bit slow, specially if it contains pictures)

    FileEncoding, UTF-8
    FileRead, content,% file_path

    Loop,%  VarSetCapacity( content )   {

        byte := NumGet( content, A_Index-1, "UChar" )
        If( byte < 32 )
            Continue

        text .= Chr( byte )

    }

    Return text

}
```

You may paste your clipboard to a file with .html extension and run it to test.

P.S.: Sorry for any grammatical errors, my English is still a work in progress.

Comment: Thanks!  The comments are pretty straightforward, but as I'm very new to AHK I can't understand even a small portion of this code.  But from what I can tell, this seems like it may be a bit over-complicated for what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm NOT trying to create a code that will work for anything.  Rather, I'm hoping for code for a single instance of text + hyperlink as in my example above.  (E.g., one for "Google" hyperlinked to https://google.com; another for "Facebook" hyperlinked to https://www.facebook.com/.  I copy and paste the same few texts with the same few hyperlinks multiple times a day, and would like to have 5 or so hotkeys for each of those specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at "my" clipboard library here: https://github.com/tdalon/ahk/blob/main/Lib/Clip.ahk

```
sText := "Google.com"
sLink := "https://google.com"
sHtml := "<a href=""" . sLink . """>" . sText . "</a>"
Clip_PasteHtml(sHtml,sLink)
```

I guess you have a timing problem between your ClipboardSetHTML and paste action.

You might want also to have a look at the WinClip library.
See for example https://tdalon.blogspot.com/2020/03/rich-text-expander.html

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up figuring out an alternative way to do this using the hyperlink shortcut (Ctrl + k) in most programs.  Here's what I've been using.                                               Takes 2 inputs (text and a URL), and hyperlinks the URL to that text.

hyperlink(Text, URL){
 SendInput %Text%
 StringLen, Length, Text
 SendInput {Shift down}
 Loop, %Length%
 {
  SendInput {Left}
 }
 SendInput {Shift up}
 SendInput {Ctrl down}k{Ctrl up}
 Sleep 250
 SendInput %URL%
 Sleep 250
 SendInput {Enter}{Right}

Comment: Ctrl+K is almost universal yes. I would think about replacing SendInput by pasting the link https://tdalon.blogspot.com/2021/04/ahk-paste-restore-clipboard-pitfall.html, especially for long links